# Javafx8 Cannot set owner once stage has been set visible

Tags: javafx-8

I have two classes, the first meant to control the modality of the 2nd class.
It has 2 Button: btn1 set the modality to none, btn2 sets the modality to APPLICATION_MODAL.
I can press only one button (it creates the window with the new stage with wanted modality) but when I close this window and I try to press the other button i always get the "Cannot set owner once stage has been set visible"

```java
//My control class:
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Blank Stage 1");
        Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
        Button okBtn2 = new Button("OK");
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(okBtn);
        root.getChildren().add(okBtn2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("A Dialog Box");
        stage.show();

    okBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
        try {
            showDialog();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    okBtn2.setOnAction(e -> {
        try {
            showDialog(stage, APPLICATION_MODAL);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
    private void showDialog(Window owner, Modality modality) throws Exception {
        BlankStage MyC = new BlankStage();
        MyC.start(BlankStage.classStage, owner, modality);
    }
    private void showDialog() throws Exception {
        BlankStage MyC = new BlankStage();
        MyC.start(BlankStage.classStage);

    }
}
//This is my2nd class:
public class BlankStage extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args); 
    }
    static Stage classStage = new Stage();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage, Window owner, Modality modality) {
        classStage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.initOwner(owner);
        primaryStage.initModality(modality);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Blank Stage");
        primaryStage.setHeight(100);
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        classStage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("No Modality Stage");
        primaryStage.setHeight(100);
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

i tried to use
- close(); and hide(); (actually they are the same). no effect.
- platform.exit(), of course it closes my whole application :)
- Showandwait in booth classes (I got more errors)

have no idea how could I close the 2nd Window permanently (or reset the modality values...:( )

Comment: Why do you have two application classes in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Your question itself holds the answer: Cannot set owner once stage has been set visible.

`Stage#initOwner` method's javadoc:

```
 Specifies the owner Window for this stage, or null for a top-level,
 unowned stage. This must be done prior to making the stage visible.

 @param owner the owner for this stage.

 @throws IllegalStateException if this property is set after the stage 
 has ever been made visible.

 @throws IllegalStateException if this stage is the primary stage.

 @defaultValue null
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is so... so be it.:)
Meanwhile I found a workaround.
I added some simple lines in Control Class:

```
private void showDialog(Window owner, Modality modality) throws Exception {
            MyCalenderModal MyC = new MyCalenderModal();
            System.out.println(MyCalenderModal.classStage.getModality());
            if (MyCalenderModal.classStage.getModality()==NONE) {
                MyC.start(MyCalenderModal.classStage, owner, modality);
            }
            else MyC.start(MyCalenderModal.classStage);

        }
```

It checks whether the 2nd window already has a modality. If yes its only shows the stage.
I have to keep in my mind, if I opened a window, I can not close it anymore until my application runs.

Comment: The solution is surely to structure your application properly in the first place.